# Postgres how to decompose this problem importing dissimilar schema, needing to "fan out" an array of categories into a categories table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am importing from a dissimilar schema; field I am importing has a comma delimited list of categories in a varchar (e.g. categories: "foo, bar, baz, boo")

```
id  name  categories
1   abc   foo,bar
2   def   baz,boo
```

Native schema has a table of category names (e.g. id 1 name:"foo", id 2 name:"bar", ...) and a table item_to_category which links the id of an item to the id of a category.

How would one go about this in SQL, Postgres specifically, what steps are taken - break it down. Is SQL the right tool for this or is there a better strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a function, iterating over all of the records and extracting the string array into a varchar[] array, iterating that, and outputting into my categories and index table. HTH someone, somewhere.

```
CREATE TABLE public.categories ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    parent Integer,
    category Text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE public.companies_categories ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    category_id Integer NOT NULL,
    company_id Integer NOT NULL
);

create or replace function scan_categories()
returns setof categories as $$ 
declare
   category_list varchar[];
   category_text varchar;
   category_id int;
   company_id int;
BEGIN

FOR category_list, company_id IN SELECT categories, id FROM public.companies
  LOOP
    IF category_list IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        FOREACH category_text IN ARRAY category_list
            LOOP
               INSERT INTO public.categories(category) VALUES (category_text) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
               SELECT id FROM public.categories INTO category_id WHERE category LIKE category_text;
               INSERT INTO companies_categories (category_id, company_id) VALUES (category_id, company_id);
            END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
$$
```